# Unable to access a functionality in a .exe that uses pydrive library

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pydrive

So I have a GUI.py file with functionality mapped to a button that when clicked, uploads files stored in a particular folder to google drive. The script works fine when I run it using vscode, but it won't work when using the same in the executable file. I am using pyinstaller to package the python file into an executable file. I am using the following command to package the script:

```
pyinstaller GUI.py  --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data "G:\Projects\ProjectA\venv\Lib\site-packages/customtkinter;customtkinter/" --add-data "G:\Projects\ProjectA\venv\Lib\site-packages/pydrive;pydrive/"
```

I tried the following:

1. --add-data "G:\Projects\ProjectA\venv\Lib\site-packages/pydrive;pydrive/" I added this statement to the command(didn't work)
2. I tried adding two json files(client_secrets and credentials) to the .spec file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.